# How to abort a failing Q promise in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Let's say I'm building a registration flow, and I have something that looks like this:

```
Q.nfcall(validateNewRegCallback, email, password)
    .fail(function(err){
        console.log("bad email/pass: " + err);
        return null;
    })
    .then(function(){
        console.log("Validated!");
    })
    .done();
```

If my registration fails, I'd like to catch it, and die.  Instead, I see both "bad email/pass" and "validated".  Why is that, and how can I abort in the first failure call?

Comment: Use `promise.catch(onRehected)` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fail` handler does catch rejected promises, but then does return a fulfilled promise (with `null` in your case), as the error was handled already…

So what can you do against this?

- Re-throw the error to reject the returned promise. It will cause the `done` to throw it.

  ```
  Q.nfcall(validateNewRegCallback, email, password).fail(function(err){
      console.log("bad email/pass: " + err);
      throw err;
  }).then(function(){
      console.log("Validated!");
  }).done();
  ```
- Handle the error after the success callback (which also handles errors *in* the success callback):

  ```
  Q.nfcall(validateNewRegCallback, email, password).then(function(){
      console.log("Validated!");
  }).fail(function(err){
      console.log("bad email/pass: " + err);
  }).done();
  ```
- Simply handle both cases on the same promise - every method does accept two callbacks:

  ```
  Q.nfcall(validateNewRegCallback, email, password).done(function(){
      console.log("Validated!");
  }, function(err){
      console.log("bad email/pass: " + err);
  };
  ```

  You also might use `.then(…, …).done()` of course.