# Node.js Abort chain in Q in different point

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a pretty long chain of check in Q, and I would to interrupt it when an error rise:

I have looked to [How to abort a failing Q promise in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821936/how-to-abort-a-failing-q-promise-in-node-js) and other answers on SO, but it seems impossible to me, that can't exist nothing else.

Example
`

```
Q().then(function(){
    return Q.ninvoke(myObject, 'save');
}).fail(functon(err){ // if error
    res.status(400).send(err.message);// like duplicate key
}).then(function(){
    add object another object to db referenced to myObject
}).fail(functon(err){ // if error
    res.status(400).send(err.message);// like connection error
}).then(function(){
    do somethinng else
}).done()
```

`

Obviously, if it can't save the first object, I would not go on through other steps, but I would exit without throwing error and blocking the execution of the server without sending the message to the client.

I tried to add two function to done(OK, REJECTED), but only OK() is called.
I would like to avoid chunking the code in 3 different functions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can gather, you don't need to do anything particularly tricky, just understand how success and failure propagate through a `.then` chain, then exploit this knowledge to get the behaviour you desire.

- the chain will continue down the "success" path as long as you keep on having success
- the chain will continue down the "fail" path as long as you keep on having failure
- if a "success" function throws an error or returns a rejected promise, then the chain will continue down the "fail" path
- if a "fail" function returns a value or a fulfilled promise, then the chain will continue down the "success" path.

This behaviour is at the heart of the [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) standard.

If you were to write your chain with a single, terminal `.fail`, then (if I understand correctly) you would get the behaviour you seek.

```
Q().then(function () {
    return Q.ninvoke(myObject, 'save');
}).then(function () {
    add object another object to db referenced to myObject
}).then(function () {
    do somethinng else
}).fail(functon (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err.message);
});
```

Here, failure at any point in the `.then` chain will cause the propageted promise to drop straight through the rest of the `.then`s and be caught by the terminal `.fail`.

This has the advantage over the code in the question, which has multiple interwoven `.fail`s. That pattern can be made to work but you need to introduce a mechanism to suppress multiple "fail" behaviour once the failure has been handled. In unusual circumstances that might be appropriate, but in general it would be regarded as messy.

The only other thing you might need in the fail handler is to distiguish between the different types of failure and act accordingly. That's pretty trivial as the formal variable `err` can be tested, eg in a switch-case structure. You appear not to need such a test as the action on failure is the same in all cases.